# SQL Query Help for checking which orders can be processed in Prestashop based on stock levels

Tags: sql, prestashop

I am looking to create an SQL Query for Prestashop that will show a list of orders that NOW have all products in stock to ship.
In our industry, some orders are placed a year or more in advance!
What I would like is a list of order IDs that have not been shipped, have all products in stock in a particular warehouse so that we can process these.
I've have a bit of a play and come up with this so far. This is not my day job so be kind!

```
SELECT
o.id_order,
od.id_order,
od.product_id,
od.product_attribute_id,
od.product_name,
od.product_quantity,
asm.wi_physical_quantity
FROM
pr_orders o
LEFT JOIN pr_order_state os
ON o.current_state = os.id_order_state AND os.shipped = 0  AND o.current_state <> 4 AND o.current_state <> 5 AND o.current_state <> 6 AND o.current_state <> 7 AND o.current_state <> 34
LEFT JOIN pr_order_detail od
ON o.id_order = od.id_order
LEFT JOIN pr_bms_advancedstock_warehouse_product asm
ON od.product_id = asm.wi_product_id AND asm.wi_warehouse_id = 12 AND asm.wi_physical_quantity >= od.product_quantity AND o.current_state <> 4 AND o.current_state <> 5 AND o.current_state <> 6 AND o.current_state <> 7 AND o.current_state <> 34
ORDER BY o.id_order ASC
```

Thanks for any help!
FYI I am on PS1.7.8.x and I also use (unfortunately as it is rubbish) BoostMyShop's Advanced Stock module for multi warehouse.

Comment: you need to provide sample data and desired output , preferably prepare a fiddle (ex:  https://dbfiddle.uk/)

Comment: Thanks, the DB for Prestashop has many tables, so I was hoping someone with PS knowledge would maybe have done this already, however, I can setup a mock DB probably...

Comment: Unfortunately, you're using some ASM module that prevents people from helping you. You could contact the module author to help you, I guess.

Comment: All the ASM is doing is listing stock of products in each warehouse. I am looking to show orders that can be shipped from stock in any warehouse.